# Error accessing image stored in Amazon S3

Tags: laravel-5, amazon-s3

I uploaded an image successfully to Amazon S3 using Laravel. When I checked the bucket online, the image was there but when I click to view it, it gives me the following error:

```
The webpage at http://.. might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

This is my upload code below:

```
$imagedata = base64_decode(request('passport'));
            $imageFile = Image::make($imagedata)->resize(150, 150)->stream();
            $imageFile = $imageFile->__toString();
            $filename = str_random(4).str_random(4).str_random(6).'.jpg';
            $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
            $s3->put('images/passport/'.$filename, $imageFile, 'public');
            $passport = $s3->url('images/passport/'.$filename);
```

I can't view this image either on my pages.

**Update**

On the view which was converted to pdf using DomPDF, the image was present using the stored url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let try to upload another image manually first. If you can view that image, maybe your upload process changed the image format.

If not, maybe the problem comes from AWS. Check further things like permission, region...

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. The error has to do with the content encoding metadata option that I set  in the S3 configuration, removing solves the problem.